# Programmatically add XML property source to current environment in Spring

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to import some XML config programmatically into my current environment in a Spring application. Here is some code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    try {
        app.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:conf.xml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error" + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `conf.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:defaults.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I also have a `defaults.properties` file in my classpath.

When I run the application, it hits the IOException catch block with the error:

```
There was an errororg.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 115; Document root element "beans", 
must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

Things I've tried:

1. Specifying the root element as "beans" in a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration. Then I got an error saying the "beans" element wasn't defined
2. Checked my Spring framework version. It is Spring 4.3.x. AFAIK doctype-style/DTD XML has been superseded by schema XML after Spring 2 (forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology for these things)
3. Tried other similarly-structured XML files

Does anyone know where the error is?

I've forked one of the Spring guides to show the problem also. My code samples are taken from there: https://github.com/jogjayr/gs-rest-service/tree/master/complete

Comment: I have cloned your code and failed to run `mvn install` because you have failed test cases.

Comment: @sunkuet02 run `mvn install -DskipTests`. The tests came with the Spring guide I forked and aren't important. Or, if you wish, pull again. I've deleted the tests dir

Comment: I have got `BUILD SUCCESS` as a result

Comment: The issue happens when you run the application. I'll update my question

Comment: Propertysource must be a properties file. Why are you making things so complex? Just add `@PropertySource("classpath:defaults.properties")` to your `Application` class.

Comment: Honest answer: that's how it was when I found the code. It doesn't seem like it's possible to programmatically add properties files to a `@PropertySource` annotation. But I've found another approach and I'll add an answer in the next day or two.